# Import images from xls sheet in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, spreadsheet

Can anybody help me in importing images from xls in ruby application. I tried 'roo', 'spreadsheet' gem to parse xls sheet, but none of them get the image from the sheet, getting **nil** everytime.

I just want to insert an image in a cell and get that image in ruby.

Can anybody help me out of this?

Answer (score 0):

What I've done in the past is "save as web page" from Excel, then parse the HTML with Nokogiri. If the document is built correctly, then you can get the URL of the picture from the img src and load it that way.